# Health Check Redis Server

Tags: java, http, redis, jedis, handshake

I have tried doing the health check of Redis Server using the below code:

```
Jedis jedis = null;
        try {
            jedis = new Jedis(System.getenv(REDIS_END_POINT), Integer.parseInt(System.getenv(REDIS_PORT)),true);
            System.out.println(jedis);
            if (jedis.ping().equalsIgnoreCase(PONG)) {
                responseFlag = true;
LOGGER.info("Redis Connection established");
            } else {
                responseFlag = false;
                LOGGER.error("The HealthCheck for this service returned: " + jedis.ping());
            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            responseFlag = false;
            LOGGER.error("Exception occurred " + exception.getMessage());
        }
```

This response flag value is my return value of the method. However, when I am trying to test the code in main method, it throws exception `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake`.

Note: In my Config file I have set the necessary environment variables.