# How do you perform a HEALTHCHECK in the Redis Docker image?

Tags: docker, redis, docker-swarm

Recently, we had an outage due to Redis being unable to write to a file system (not sure why it's Amazon EFS) anyway I noted that there was no actual HEALTHCHECK set up for the Docker service to make sure it is running correctly, Redis is up so I can't simply use `nc -z` to check if the port is open.

Is there a command I can execute in the `redis:6-alpine` (or non-alpine) image that I can put in the `healthcheck` block of the `docker-compose.yml` file.

Note I am looking for command that is available **internally** in the image.  Not an [external healthcheck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60539942/health-check-redis-server).

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Although the `ping` operation from @nitrin0 answer generally works.  It does not handle the case where the write operation will actually fail.  So instead I perform a change that will just increment a value to a key I don't plan to use.

```
image: redis:6
healthcheck:
  test: [ "CMD", "redis-cli", "--raw", "incr", "ping" ]
```

Note this MUST NOT be performed on a cluster that is initialized by Docker.  Since this health check will prevent the cluster from being formed as the Redis are not empty.

Comment: if you have a password for redis, you can use:   test: [ "CMD", "redis-cli", "-a", "password", "--raw", "incr", "ping" ]

Answer (score 43):

If I remember correctly that image includes `redis-cli` so, maybe, something along these lines:

```
...
healthcheck:
   test: ["CMD", "redis-cli","ping"]
```

Answer (score 35):

I've just noticed that there is a phase in which redis is still starting up and loading data. In this phase, `redis-cli ping` shows the error

```
LOADING Redis is loading the dataset in memory
```

but stills returns the exit code `0`, which would make redis already report has healthy.

Also `redis-cli --raw incr ping` returns `0` in this phase without actually incrementing this key successfully.

As a workaround, I'm checking whether the `redis-cli ping` actually prints a `PONG`, which it only does after the LOADING has been finished.

```yaml
services:
  redis:
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "redis-cli ping | grep PONG"]
      interval: 1s
      timeout: 3s
      retries: 5
```

This works because `grep` returns only `0` when the string ("PONG") is found.

Comment: `[ "$(redis-cli ping)" = "PONG" ]` for exact match

Comment: Adding to that, here is how it can look in the yaml:
`test: "[ $$(redis-cli -a $REDIS_PASSWORD ping) = 'PONG' ]"`

Comment: Or simply `test: redis-cli -a ${REDIS_PASSWORD} ping | grep PONG` using grep. Note, this is equivalent to `CMD-SHELL` per https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/

Comment: Or if you're using Docker secrets: `test: ["CMD-SHELL", "redis-cli --no-auth-warning -a \"$$(cat $$REDIS_PASSWORD_FILE)\" ping | grep PONG"]`

Comment: Redis does not recommend use of `-a` and `-u` options for providing auth password. Here is what I came up with: `test: ["CMD-SHELL", "echo 'auth ${REDIS_PASSWORD}\nping' | redis-cli | grep PONG"]`

Comment: If docker is configured to restart unhealthy containers, I would either recommend setting a `start_period` corresponding to the expected Redis loading time or not to use `grep PONG`. When starting up redis, loading the dataset in memory is a healthy state...even if the redis server is not usable.

Answer (score 4):

You can also add it inside the Dockerfile if your using a Redis image that contains the redis-cli:

Linux Docker

```
HEALTHCHECK CMD redis-cli ping || exit 1
```

Windows Docker

```
HEALTHCHECK CMD pwsh.exe -command \
try { \
    $response = ./redis-cli ping; \
    if ($response -eq 'PONG') { return 0} else {return 1}; \
} catch { return 1 }
```