# Unreachable network with Docker-compose and network_mode

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, docker-compose, docker-network, vscode-remote

Docker beginner here.
I have 3 services (webapp, database, and redis) that need to share the same network.

When I build my container using Docker compose (via VS Code remote containers), sometimes everything's fine. Sometimes, the redis service is not accessible (`connecting to 127.0.0.1:6379. Connection refused`). And even sometimes both the database and redis are not accessible.

Running `ss` on debian, I can see the `6379` port is not open.
[image]

I used the `network_mode: service:[foo]` strategy, as you can see below in my docker-compose.yml file:

```yaml
version: "3"

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: ..
      dockerfile: .devcontainer/service_app/Dockerfile

    volumes:
      - ..:/workspace:delegated

    # Overrides default command so things don't shut down after the process ends.
    command: sleep infinity

  db:
    network_mode: service:app
    env_file: service_db/.env.local
    build:
      context: ..
      dockerfile: .devcontainer/service_db/Dockerfile
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - "pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data"

  rd:
    network_mode: service:app
    image: redis:7
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - "rddata:/data"

volumes:
  pgdata:
  rddata:
```

Note that I tried another strategy which was to not use `network_mode` and reach my service using `rd:6379` rather than `127.0.0.1:6379`. It worked but curiously, it hanged 3 seconds before establishing the connection, which is painful.

What did I do wrong? Thanks.

Comment: `network_mode: service` is very unusual and I'd recommend the last approach you describe, deleting `network_mode:` and configuring the service to use the Compose service name `rd` as a host name.  That shouldn't take multiple seconds to connect, though.

Comment: @DavidMaze can you elaborate about why is it unusual/bad? I followed the recommandation here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/create-dev-container#_using-localhost-in-docker-compose

Comment: @DavidDahan according to the descr, this network mode is used to expose another container on the localhost of the container, this is not a usual practice, unless you really need this. I recommend trying with a default network mode

Answer (score 1):

Looks like starting order problem.

`app` is depending on both `rd` and `db`. So you have to start `rd` and `db` first and only after that `app` may be started. You may add [dependencies](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#depends_on) to keep correct order.

Good way:

```yaml
version: "3"

services:
  app:
    depends_on:
      - db
      - rd
    ...

  db:
    ...

  rd:
    ...
```

In this case `app` will be started last.

But! It is still not perfect. After starting `db` and and `rd` docker don't wait while internal processes will be ready for requests. So best way is to wait while `rd` and `db` will be healthy:

```yaml
version: "3"

services:
  app:
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
      rd:
        condition: service_healthy
    ...

  db:
    healthcheck:
      test: <command to check if service healthy>
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 10s
    ...

  rd:
    healthcheck:
      test: <command to check if service healthy>
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 10s
    ...
```

If your `app` starting longer than `db` and `rd` first way should work. But if you not sure about start time implementing of [healthcheck](https://scoutapm.com/blog/how-to-use-docker-healthcheck) will make your infrastructure more stable.

Some examples how to implement healthcheck with [redis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67904609/how-do-you-perform-a-healthcheck-in-the-redis-docker-image) and... I don't know what DB is used, so try to google by yourself

Comment: Thanks. I should have specify that I use Docker for local development only, so healthcheck is not necessary: since I start commands by hand, my 3 containers will be ready at that time. For the initial problem, as I mentioned at the end of my first post, removing `network_mode` works, but on a random basis, curiously, connecting to the server hangs 3 to 5 seconds before establishing the connection, which is painful. Maybe I should do another post with that specific problem.

Comment: Yep. Looks like that is not docker problem. That will be better to specify 1. is `hangs 3 to 5 seconds` happens only with redis or both redis and db has this problem? 2. I can see `restart: unless-stopped`, so it is possible that redis everytime restarting and you need to wait 3 seconds before it start handle request and fail again. 3. You mentioned that `6379 port is not open`. What happening with container in this time (`docker ps -a | grep rd`)?

Comment: I wrote another question to avoid mixing topics together: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72856901/network-hanging-5-seconds-with-vs-code-remote-docker-containers Thanks!