# Network hanging 5 seconds with VS Code remote Docker containers

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, docker-compose, vscode-remote, vscode-devcontainer

I have 3 services: webapp (app), database (db), and redis (rd) that share the same network.
Randomly, both connections to the services (database and redis) hangs about 5 seconds.
It's not only when I run my webserver that connects to the database, but even when I browse a link on a web page. At some point it freezes and need to wait for about 5 seconds.

I'm not sure but it looks like the connection is automatically closed at some point and need to be re-established.

I don't know I'm supposed to debug this:

- Running `telnet db 5432` or `telnet rd 5432` in my app container will always work instantly.
- Running docker ps -a in my host machine display this:
  [image]

Here is my docker-compose file:

```yaml
version: "3"

services:
  app:
    depends_on:
      - db
      - rd
    build:
      context: ..
      dockerfile: .devcontainer/service_app/Dockerfile

    volumes:
      - ..:/workspace:delegated

    # Avoid having the container shut down if the default container command fails or exits
    command: /bin/sh -c "while sleep 1000; do :; done"

  db:
    env_file: service_db/.env.local
    build:
      context: ..
      dockerfile: .devcontainer/service_db/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - "pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data"

  rd:
    image: redis:7
    volumes:
      - "rddata:/data"

volumes:
  pgdata:
  rddata:
```

I don't understand what could cause this. Thanks.

Comment: Check DNS and IPv4/6. Otherwise, assuming it's networking, you'll want to start tracking this with tcpdump at various points along the connection (client, firewalls, destination).

Comment: @BMitch when running tcpdump, I can see that absolutely nothing happens when it's hanging. Does it mean the problem could be unrelated to network?

Comment: Maybe, or it could be waiting for a response. There's not enough detail to answer.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: @ikhvjs host OS: last MacOS - container OS: last Debian

Comment: I am not sure the reason, but what if you replace `sleep infinity` to `/bin/sh -c "while sleep 1000; do :; done"`? I guess sleep infinity may ultilize the container memory...

Comment: @ikhvjs Good try but it did not change anything. Question updated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace your sleep loop with `tail -f /dev/null`

Comment: It didn't change anything.

Comment: What about file handles limit on your Mac? Check it with: sudo launchctl limit maxflies. By default it's too little, you should probably increase it.